Error 400 [no body] when trying to send a GraphQL Request with HttpSyncGraphQlClient in Spring Boot 3.3.1
I have a Java 21 Spring Boot 3.3.1 using MVC application. I used to send GraphQL requests with RestClient and just built the GraphQL body manually. Since I am using MVC, I could not use the HttpGraphQlClient, but now that Spring Boot 3.3.1 has the HttpSyncGraphQlClient, I am trying to use that.
    private final RestClient restClient;
    private final HttpSyncGraphQlClient graphQlClient;

    public MyHttpClient() {
        this.restClient = RestClient.builder().build();
        this.graphQlClient = HttpSyncGraphQlClient.create(restClient);
    }

    public <T> T sendGraphQlReq(String url, String graphQlName, Map<String, Object> variables, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType) {
        var response = graphQlClient.mutate()
                .url(url)
                .headers(headers -> headers.addAll(RequestContextHolder.getHttpHeaders()))
                .build()
                .documentName(graphQlName)
                .variables(variables)
                .retrieveSync(graphQlName)
                .toEntity(responseType);

        logger.info("GraphQL request response: {}", response);

        return response;
    }

I am not sending requests to a single GraphQL endpoint, and I do not know which one I will be sending it to first, so that is how I set up the client. It shows that in the docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/reference/client.html
The headers are retrieved from a context holder, and that works with my normal REST request my app makes with the RestClient. And the url is used in other RestClient requests as well that work.
I know that the graphQlClient is able to get the document, where I have my GraphQL request defined (main/resources/graphql-documents/myRequest.graphql). If I move the graphql resource file, I get a different error saying it cannot find the document.
I am not sure what is causing the error, but I get an HttpClientErrorException Bad Request when I try to send requests, and there is no other error message.

nothing looks out of place in your code snippet. Can you share more about the error (is there an error message somehow), or can you log the request headers and share those here?

@BrianClozel I went back to how I was doing it before. I will update it again soon to test. There are no error messages. All it shows is Bad Request [no body], but I was assuming the .documentName(graphQlName) generated the body. Unless the error message was saying there was no body for the error message.
When I use GraphQLTester in my unit tests, I have it set up similarly, and it works just fine. The .documentName() gets the document and creates the body.
